# Code to split delimiter string

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am a newby of learning Progress OpenEdge. I have a question about how to split a string input from user to get the output with the delimiter in one procedure.

For example,

With input

```
"A0020000A103A0A0A0A501A4A405A5A5A5A5A5"
```

The output should be:

```
HEADER  LEN  DATA
-------------   ------   --------------
A0              02   0000
A1              03   A0A0A0
A5              01   A4
A4              05   A5A5A5A5A5
```

Or

With input :

```
"B103X0X0X0C204B1B1B1B1A209C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2X301A2"
```

Output:

```
HEADER  LEN  DATA
-------------   ------   -----------------------
B1              03    X0X0X0
C2              04    B1B1B1B1
A2              09    C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2
X3              01    A2
```

Comment: With your examples, one can say that there can be exactly 2 characters for "Header" and "Len". But, how do you decide the number of characters for "Data". There should be some criteria to split the string. What's the criteria?
And, did you write some code to achieve this? If yes, post the code. OpenEdge version and OS information will also be helpful for others to suggest you something.

Answer (score 1):

I have attempted to reverse-engineer your requirements from your output.

It looks like the data is in two-character chunks.  A "header" followed by a "counter" field and then however many two-character "data" fields the counter indicates.

This appears to break up the string in the way that you desire:

```
define variable data as character no-undo format "x(60)".

function getElements returns integer ( input str as character ):
  return integer( substring( str, 1, 2 )).
end.


function getData returns character ( input str as character ):
  return substring( str, 3, getElements( str ) * 2 ).
end.

procedure parse:

  define input parameter str as character no-undo.

  define variable ii as integer no-undo.
  define variable jj as integer no-undo.

  define variable nn as integer no-undo.

  nn = length( str ).
  ii = 1.

  do while ii < nn:

    display
      substring( str, ii, 2 )
      substring( str, ii + 2, 2 )
    .

    data = getData( substring( str, ii + 2 )).

    display data.

    pause.

    ii = ii + 4 + length( data ).

  end.

  return.

end.

run parse ( "A0020000A103A0A0A0A501A4A405A5A5A5A5A5" ).
run parse ( "B103X0X0X0C204B1B1B1B1A209C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2X301A2" ).

return.
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as Tom's answer but without the functions and with display formatting.

```
procedure parse:
  define input parameter i_c as character no-undo.

  def var itotal  as int  no-undo.
  def var ipos    as int  no-undo initial 1.

  def var cheader as char no-undo label "Header" format "x(2)".
  def var ilen    as int  no-undo label "Len"    format "99".
  def var cdata   as char no-undo label "Data"   format "x(50)".

  itotal = length( i_c ).

  repeat while ipos < itotal:

    assign
      cheader = substring( i_c, ipos, 2 )
      ilen    = integer( substring( i_c, ipos + 2, 2 ) )
      cdata   = substring( i_c, ipos + 4, 2 * ilen )            
      ipos    = ipos + 4 + ilen * 2
      .

    display
      cheader
      ilen 
      cdata
    with width 70.

  end.

end procedure.

run parse ( "A0020000A103A0A0A0A501A4A405A5A5A5A5A5" ).
run parse ( "B103X0X0X0C204B1B1B1B1A209C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2C2X301A2" ).
```

- variables with labels and formats are used
- repeat has block handling so that all records are shown below each other
- I am fully aware that Tom will complain about the variable name datatype prefixes but they beat the hell out of ii, jj and nn and using convulted names to avoid a conflict with a progress keyword is just not worth it (imho)

Comment: Now I'm obligated to complain ;)  Normally I'd just say "i" and "j" but I'm finding the idea of ii and jj as being much more searchable to be kind of attractive so I thought I'd try it out, see what it looks like and check to see if my fingers burn after typing it.

Comment: Single character variables are an abomination that should have died out when 16-bit cpus were introduced. Another option for the strict compile option ;-)

Comment: I've always been fond of i, j and k for loop counters :)